# Undefined reference to symbol acos@@GLIBC_2.2.5 while compiling xpdf

Tags: compiling, gcc, make, c, glibc

I get the following error while compiling xpdf using `make`. I've tried using the command: `LIBS=-l make` but it doesn't work. I know the problem is that the c compiler cannot recognise the math code in the source code because the math library is not available to it, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
[ 71%] Linking CXX executable pdftohtml 
    /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/xpdf_objs.dir/Gfx.cc.o: undefined reference to symbol 'acos@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
    //usr/lib64/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[2]: *** [xpdf/CMakeFiles/pdftohtml.dir/build.make:219: xpdf/pdftohtml] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:428: xpdf/CMakeFiles/pdftohtml.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

I have put my [Makefile](https://pastebin.com/hFCR77Ts) and [CmakeLists.txt](https://pastebin.com/3cFJLS1Y) on pastebin for more information.

Comment: Well, the issue seems to be that your link command is missing `-lm` ("DSO missing from command line") but I don't know enough about cmake to suggest a fix - and it's probably more a question for stackoverflow than for askubuntu

Comment: @steeldriver I was thinking thesame. I don't quite know how to add it to the command line.

Comment: Something like this perhaps? [Math functions not working with “make” in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365070/math-functions-not-working-with-make-in-c/36365412#36365412)

Comment: @steeldriver  thanks for the link. I read it but I couldn't find the code `add_executable` in the CmakeList.txt file.

Comment: So whose code is it? where did you get it? did you write the CMakeList.txt file yourself?

Comment: Its not my code. Its from this  [program](https://www.xpdfreader.com/). This is probably caused by how the code was written

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78810/discussion-between-steeldriver-and-mywrathacademia).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging the code, the solution I used was to add `-lpaper` to the `DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` or the `DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` during the `cmake` command, either works. Thanks @steeldriver for very good insights.